# What regex expression stands for a double line?

Tags: regex

I want to write a simple program that replaces double (or triple blank) lines by single lines.
So for instance:

```
line1



line2
```

becomes:

```
line1

line2
```

How would I do that?  \n does not seem to work.  I don't want to use string.replace, I want to use regular expressions, for various reasons.

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: Why does \n not work? Maybe there are some carriage returns in there?

Comment: If `\n` does not work, `\r\n` will. Or a `\R` if it is PCRE. Or `(?:\r?\n|\r)`. If multiple, add quantifiers: `(?:\r?\n|\r){2,}` for 2 or more...

Comment: Please add the language (or regex flavor), and expected output. Otherwise, it is not answering, it is guessing, and it is really something no one likes here.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
var pattern = "(\n)+";
var validSample = "\n\n\n\n";    

Console.WriteLine( Regex.Replace(validSample, pattern, "\n"));
```

Comment: How come you know it is C#? OP said `\n` did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this regex. `(\r?\n){2,}`. [Test here](http://regexr.com/3c4gu).

You'll probably need to escape the `\` in the pattern's string.

Comment: On regexr.com, you cannot test carriage returns.

Comment: You're right, but I don't know any site where you can. Do you know any? I used the link so that OS could see that online multiple line-breaks matched.

Comment: You can test them at online regex testers for .NET regex: regexstorm.net and regexhero.net.

Answer (score 0):

vague answer for a vague question...

```
[\n\r][\n\r]+
```

Will work in [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), [php](/questions/tagged/php) and [python](/questions/tagged/python): [see example here](https://regex101.com/r/qF2sF2/2)